# How to do transactions in python with asyncio and postgres?

Tags: python, postgresql, transactions, async-await, python-asyncio

There are two operations in my RPC method:

```
async def my_rpc(self, data):
    async with self.Engine() as conn:
        await conn.execute("SELECT ... FROM MyTable");
        ...  # It seems the table MyTable can be changed by another RPC
        await conn.execute("UPDATA MyTable ...");
```

Another RPC method can change DB before operation "my_rpc" will be done (between two awaits of SQL queries). How to avoid this situation?

Code of self.Engine (calls with engine `aiopg.sa.create_engine`):

```
class ConnectionContextManager(object):
    def __init__(self, engine):
        self.conn = None
        self.engine = engine

    async def __aenter__(self):
        if self.engine:
            self.conn = await self.engine.acquire()
            return self.conn

    async def __aexit__(self, exc_type, exc, tb):
        try:
            self.engine.release(self.conn)
            self.conn.close()
        finally:
            self.conn = None
            self.engine = None
```

Comment: can you show your code for self.Engine ?

Comment: @jsbueno I added code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, `aiopg` works in autocommit mode, meaning that you have to use transaction in manual mode. [Read more details](http://aiopg.readthedocs.io/en/stable/core.html#transactions).

Secondly, you have to use SELECT FOR UPDATE for lock row that you read in first statement. SELECT FOR UPDATE locks select rows while until the transaction completes. [Read more details](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-select.html#SQL-FOR-UPDATE-SHARE).

```
async def my_rpc(self, data):
    async with self.Engine() as conn:
        await conn.execute("BEGIN")
        await conn.execute("SELECT ... FROM MyTable WHERE some_clause = some_value FOR UPDATE")
        ...  # It seems the table MyTable can be changed by another RPC
        await conn.execute("UPDATE MyTable SET some_clause=...")
        await conn.execute("""COMMIT""")
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the only way to avoid confusion is to have each transaction to take place in a separate database connection (Python side cursors won't do)
The way to do that is to have a connection pool - and have your Engine method deliver a different connection for each "async thread".

That would be easier if the connector to the Postgresql itself would be async-aware  (which driver are you using, btw?). Or a database-wrapper layer above it.  If it is not, you will have to implement this connection pool yourself. I think Sqlalchemy connection pools will work just right fot that case, as, independent of being used in a co-routine, a connection will only be freed at the end of the `async with` block.

Comment: I have not tested my code yet.
But there are used separate connections from the "aiopg.sa".
Maybe this is just what I need?

Comment: Yes .  since you are getting your connection with the call in `async with` and using a connector ready for asyncio, that should be all you need.

Comment: I think so not all... you have to use transaction manually and also SELECT FOR UPDATE